# Does the complement of sigma Kleene star exist?

Tags: formal-languages

If $\Sigma^*$ is the set of ALL strings including the empty string, then what can its complement possibly be?  The empty set?

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ contains the empty string, not the empty set. And yes, its complement with respect to $\Sigma^*$ is, of course, $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the complement of all possible strings<sup>1</sup> is no strings at all. A machine that decides $\Sigma^*$ accepts every input; a machine that decides the complement of $\Sigma^*$ rejects every input.

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, all finite strings over some fixed alphabet $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the complement of $A \subseteq \Sigma^*$ is defined as $\Sigma^* \setminus A$; so yes: the complement of $\Sigma^*$ itself is the empty set.

To be completely accurate, you need to state with respect to *which universe* you want to take the complement. For instance, if you were to take the complement of $\Sigma^*$ w.r.t. $\Sigma'^*$ where $\Sigma' = \Sigma \mathbin{\dot\cup} \{a\})^*$, $a \not\in \Sigma$, it would not be empty but $\Sigma'^* \cdot \{a\} \cdot \Sigma'^*$ (the set of words with at least one $a$).